# How can I override or remove previous events with new loaded events in full calendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

```
On fullcalendar init, I have : 

$("#m_supervisor_calendar").fullCalendar({      
      events: function (start, end, timezome, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/calendarSchedule/getCalendarData',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (events) {
                callback(events)
            }
        })
},
```

But I need to have a `button` on click will change the events source and remove previous events. It's working at first i.e it is clearing previous events and showing the new rendered events but when I click on `prev` `next` month buttons. It shows all events i.e previous one and the new  ones.

```
$('button').on('click', function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: ''fetch/calendarByVolunteer',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (events) {
            $("#m_supervisor_calendar").fullCalendar('removeEvents');
            $("#m_supervisor_calendar").fullCalendar('addEventSource', response);
            $("#m_supervisor_calendar").fullCalendar('rerenderEvents', response);
        }
   })

})
```

so I want is that previous events to be completely removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of fetching the events yourself i would advise to use an event Source. Read [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/event-source-object) about event Source as JSON feed.

Then fullcalendar has the option to dynamically [add](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/addEventSource) or [remove](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/removeEventSource) event sources.

Inside your function you then can remove the source and add another source to the calendar

```
$("#m_supervisor_calendar").fullCalendar({
  eventSources: [
{
 id: 'mySource'
 url: 'fetch/calendarByVolunteer',
}
]
});
```

and then in your button function

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
 $("#m_supervisor_calendar").fullCalendar( ‘removeEventSource’, 'mySource' )
});
```

**Edit**:
[removing all sources](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/removeEventSources):

> If optionalSourcesArray is not given, all event sources will be removed.

so use something like this

```
$("#m_supervisor_calendar").fullCalendar( ‘removeEventSource’)
```

**Edit2** refetching
According to the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/lazyFetching) about lazyFetching

> When set to false, the calendar will fetch events any time the view is switched, or any time the current date changes (for example, as a result of the user clicking prev/next).

You need to set it as a calendar option when you first init the calendar.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
eventSources: [ 
{
 id: 'mySource'
 url: 'fetch/calendarByVolunteer',
}
],
lazyFetching: false, 
});
```

Now everytime you navigate or change the view, your eventSource will be called and the start and end variable will be passed as `get` parameters to that. 
For example if your eventSource is `myfeed.php` and the calendar is supposed to display events starting `2019-12-01` and ending `2019-12-5`, the fullcalendar will make a get request that looks like this:

`/myfeed.php?start=2019-12-01&end=2019-12-05`

Comment: okay, but the code above is not showing what i described in my answer...

Comment: oh its working now... is there another way that I can remove all the event sources?

Comment: yes just pass no ID to the removeEventSource and then all will be removed. 

    ` $("#m_supervisor_calendar").fullCalendar( ‘removeEventSource’) `

Comment: how can i attach start-date and end-date on the url how can i get it fullCalendar

Comment: @ReyYoung by default fullcalendar will add two get parameters when calling your eventsource. by default they are named `start` and `end`. You can read more about that [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-json-feed)

Comment: @ReyYoung set [lazy Fetching](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/lazyFetching) to false. If you do that the calendar will fetch the events everytime you change the view or change the date

Comment: Okay @john thanks.. its not working.. where should i place it can you please update your answer?